# Is there a way to make a bot give everyone a role?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So im trying to get my bot to give every single member in the discord a specific role. Anyone know how?

Here's my code:

```
@commands.command()
@commands.has_role('Administrator')
async def roleall(self, ctx, *, role):
member = member.guild 
for member in m:
  await member.add_roles(role)
  await asyncio.sleep(5)
  self.client.get_channel(850067146880712714)
  embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Roles!", description=f"{ctx.author} gave everyone the {role} role.", color=0xff0000)
  await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: What is the question here? You provided some code but no further explanation. Is something wrong with the code?

Comment: The code is not indented correctly and will not run. That's *a* problem. The body of a function must be indented per normal Python indentation rules.

Answer (score 0):

You have to request all the `member` in a different way. As you can't just request `guild` in the way you wanted to, we have to use `ctx.guild` and get all the `members` from it.

I also don't understand why you request a channel but don't use it, otherwise you could have just used `ctx.send`. So we define `client.get_channel()` as `channel` and then send in there the message.

Also, to prevent the bot from always sending the embed when it has assigned the role to a user, we send the embed when the `for` loop is over.

**Have a look at the following code:**

```py
@commands.command()
@commands.has_role('Administrator')
async def roleall(self, ctx, *, role: discord.Role):
    for member in ctx.guild.members: # For loop for all member in the guild
        await member.add_roles(role) # Add the role to all users
    channel = client.get_channel(850067146880712714) # Define a channel
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Roles!", description=f"{ctx.author} gave everyone the {role} role.", color=0xff0000)
    await channel.send(embed=embed) # Send it to the defined channel
```

- The role can either be mentioned, you can insert the ID or just the name.
- **Please also note that Python is very prone to proper indentation.**